# Next iteration on $.each success or true jQuery ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

Is there a way to wait in iteration and go next if the ajax call is true/success?

My jQuery code that make the first call, get all products and then process it one by one:

```
$(document).on( "click", '#doJob',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var product_id = 0;
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:"<?php echo './url/products'; ?>",    
            data: {product_id: product_id},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                if(data.status == 'success'){
                    $.each(data.data, function(i,item){
                        storeTempProduct(item.product_id);
                        //if storeTempProduct == true Continue to next iteration
                        var percentage = Math.ceil((i/data.total)*1000)/10;
                        $('#test').html('<p>Processing... '+percentage+'%</p>');
                    });
                    return false;
                }
            }
    });
});

function storeTempProduct(product_id){
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:"<?php echo './url/storeEachProduct'; ?>",    
            data: {product_id: product_id},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                if(data.status == 'success'){
                    return true;
                }
            }
    });
}
```

Also i would like to know if on the $.each iteration can be set multiple calls, let's say, 3 or 5 calls at each containing 5 products ids.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Yes, this could be done with some clever use of [promises](http://joseoncode.com/2011/09/26/a-walkthrough-jquery-deferred-and-promise/) However, it would be far easier to do all of this porocessing on the server side. Just send all of your info to the server. The server logic can halt whenever something is false and return a warning or something. If all are true, it can send the data to `/url/storeEachProduct` and return the results of that. Stacking a bunch of needless Ajax calls on the client side would be a very poor design IMHO